# syntax error for copy command in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, bulkinsert

I used the command:

```
﻿COPY studentapp_deg_course_cat(degree_code, specialization, category_level1, category_level2, category_level3, min_credit, max_credit, primary)
FROM '/home/abhishek/Downloads/courses.csv'
USING DELIMITERS ';'
```

and i am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "﻿COPY" LINE 1: ﻿COPY studentapp_deg_course_cat(degree_code, specialization,...
        ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "﻿COPY" SQL state: 42601 Character: 1
```

I would like to know the error in my code

Comment: Your version of Postgres? Your OS?

Comment: i am using ubuntu 13.04 and postgres version is 9.1.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid [`COPY` syntax for version 9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-copy.html) on Linux should be:

```
COPY studentapp_deg_course_cat(degree_code, specialization, category_level1,
            category_level2, category_level3, min_credit, max_credit, "primary")
FROM '/home/abhishek/Downloads/courses.csv'
WITH (DELIMITER ';')
```

`WITH`, not <strike>`USING`</strike>.
`DELIMITER` instead of <strike>`DELIMITERS`</strike>.

And do not use `primary` as column name. [It's a reserved word.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html)

Comment: Hi i tried the command you gave and i am still getting the same error..There are a few blank spaces in the cells of the csv file. Might that be a reason?

Comment: @AbhishekReddy: No, you get a syntax error. You never even get that far ... Found & fixed another one.